# Rotate rigidbody with moverotation in the direction of the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, direction

I want to use moverotation to rotate the object in the direction of the Main Camera, like a common third person shooter, but I don't know how to set the quaternion values or otherwise

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movimento : MonoBehaviour
{

   [SerializeField] float walk = 1;
   [SerializeField] float run = 2;
    Vector3 movement = Vector3.zero;
    private Rigidbody rig;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
      rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) walk = (walk + run);
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)) walk = (walk - run);

        float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");.
        float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        movement = Camera.main.transform.forward * Vertical + Camera.main.transform.right * Horizontal;
        float origMagnitude = movement.magnitude;
        movement.y = 0f;
        movement = movement.normalized * origMagnitude;

    }

     private void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        rig.MovePosition(rig.position + movement * walk * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(???);
        rig.MoveRotation(rig.rotation * rotation);


    }
  }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use a coroutine to do smooth rotation. I use [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) for the job.

so you indicate the position of object to look at and the duration of animation.  Here you want to rotate face to the main camera

```
StartCoroutine(SmoothRotation(Camera.main.transform, 3f));
:
:

IEnumerator SmoothRotation(Transform target, float duration)
{
    float currentDelta = 0;
    var startrotation = transform.rotation;//use your rigisbody if you want here i use the gameobject
    var LookPos = target.position - transform.position;
    var finalrot = Quaternion.LookRotation(LookPos);


    while (currentDelta <= 1f)
    {
        currentDelta += Time.deltaTime / duration;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(startrotation, finalrot, currentDelta);//
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.rotation = finalrot;
}
```

if you want to see (in scene when running) where your camera points just add this line of code in update():

```
    Debug.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * 10f, Color.black);
```

if you want to point in same direction tha nthe Camera just change the line of finalrot in SmoothRotation Method:

```
var finalrot = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
```

you dont need to calculate the LookPos

for your problem of crazy rotation, i suggest you to reset rotation x and z

```
direction = hit.transform.position - transform.position;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
rotation.x = 0f;
rotation.z = 0f;
```

a tips to detect object what you want with the raycast inside spere : [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html):  you could select what you want to cast when using the optional parameter [layermask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)

```
private void DetectEnemy(Vector3 center, float radius)
{

    var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius );

    for (var i = 0; i < hitColliders.Length; i++)
    {
        print(hitColliders[i].name + "," + hitColliders[i].transform.position);
        // collect information on the hits here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but how do I match "target position" with the direction the camera is pointing? ..

Comment: you speak about the direction of camera not where it is pointing....what do you mean by pointing..???  Camera.main.transform.rotation is the direction where the camera points

Comment: if i use Camera.main.transform.rotation for the "target" position it gives me a mistake. I want to create an x - transform.position vector, to be used on Quaternion.LookRotation. Where x is the rotation position of the camera. I have also just installed a raycast on the main camera, so as to use it as a vector for the unknown "x" but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I created a raycast from the camera, and I would like to rotate the rigidbody to where the raycast is pointing but if i launch unity, it rotated wildly. What is the error?

```
     Vector3 direction;
  Vector3 rayDir = new Vector3(Screen.width/2,Screen.height/2);

void Update()

Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(rayDir);
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, Color.yellow);
RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
direction = hit.point - transform.position;

private void FixedUpdate ()
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
  rig.MoveRotation(rig.rotation * rotation);
```

Comment: what do you mean by widly?   instantly.?

Comment: that goes crazy, and rotates as fast as a drill in all directions.  I just want to use MoveRotation to rotate it in the direction the camera is facing but I can't match the rotation of the rigidbody with the position of the raycast that I created, or with another method useful for the purpose

Comment: .see my modified answer, you have to reset rotation x and z...

Comment: and you have to be sure that is the good object which is hitted....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. unfortunately the result does not change. At this point I want to eliminate the raycast solution. Do you have a suggestion/script to rotate the object with MoveRotation, in the direction the main.camera, is facing?

Answer (score 0):

Add a character controller component, this is what is for. See:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html

Comment: I already use the rigidbody, there is no need for the controller, I just want to use MoveRotation to rotate it in the direction the camera is facing